# Angular2 how to pass a parameter into a custom form control validator?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I wrote a very simple form control validator:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

function checkboxRequiredValidator(c: AbstractControl) {
    return c.value ? null : {
        required: true
    };
}



@Directive({
    selector: '[checkbox-required-validator]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, multi: true, useValue: checkboxRequiredValidator }
    ]
})
export class CheckboxRequiredValidator {

}
```

I would like to pass a message parameter to it which I can return. I tried this, but it won't work:

```
function checkboxRequiredValidator(c: AbstractControl, msg) {
    return c.value ? null : {
        message: msg
    };
}


@Directive({
    selector: '[checkbox-required-validator]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, multi: true, useValue: checkboxRequiredValidator }
    ]
})
export class CheckboxRequiredValidator {
    @Input('checkbox-required-validator') msg:  = 'default message';

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the directive itself the validator. That way you can use the message input.

```
import { forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[checkbox-required-validator]',
  providers: [
    { 
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxRequiredValidator )
    }
  ]
})
export class CheckboxRequiredValidator implements Validator {
  @Input('checkbox-required-validator') msg  = 'default message';

  validate(c: AbstractControl) {
    return c.value ? null : {
      required: this.msg
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: This will also work with model data that you wish to pass as long as you interpolate it ({{ model.property }})

Comment: @GlennBullock how would you be able to pass model data in? When I do this, I always get can't bind errors.

Comment: By renaming the Input variable to the name of the custom validator, you can call the validator on the form element by using "[checkbox-required-validator]="custom message"

Comment: You still need to declare the directive in a module if you are getting "can't bind errors"

Answer (score 8):

you can change your existing function and add an agrument to the closure, you can also add it to your own custom validators class like so (and for example write a maxVal function) :

```
export class MyValidators
{
        public static maxVal(maxVal: number) {
        return (c: FormControl) => {
            return c.value > maxVal ?
                { 'maxVal': { 'MaxValue': maxVal, 'actualValue': c.value } } :
                null;           
        }
    }
```

and then use it in your FormControl, and send the argument(for example, 100) to the validator function:

```
let fc:FormControl = new FormControl('name', MyValidators.maxVal(100));
```